# Feynman Diagrams with feynMF and feynMP

Tags: feynmf

Im triying to learn how to draw Feynman diagrams by using feynMF which I installed from [this link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmf) and compiled. however even in this simple example which I took from [manual](http://mirror.isoc.org.il/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf) it gave me `! I detected a fmfgraph environment outside of fmffile. ! I detected a fmfgraph environment outside of fmffile.` these errors. how can I fix this problem? thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{feynmf}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{4}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Every `fmfgraph` environment must be enclosed inside an `fmffile` environment.

Comment: Im sorry but I don't know what does this mean

Comment: I see. I used following code but this time it draws nothing:
\begin{fmffile}{simple}
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

Comment: You have to run Metafont or Metapost (depending on whether you load `feynmf` or `feynmp`). See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nowadays it's better using `feynmp` rather than `feynmf`, because it's easier to produce the pictures. `feynmp` also has the distinct feature of using Metapost, which produces `EPS` vector graphics, while FeynMF uses Metafont, which produces bitmaps. According to Thorsten Ohl, the creator of this package, `feynmf` is outdated.

In any case you have to tell the package the name of the auxiliary file where the Metapost code is to be written, which is done by opening a `fmffile` environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{} % for being able to read the produced file

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{afilename}% choose something better!
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{4}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

After running LaTeX, you have to run `mpost afilename` and then recompile. If you have a fairly recent TeX distribution, you can use `feynmp-auto`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{afilename}% choose something better!
\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,v3,o1}
\fmf{fermion}{o2,v4,v2,i2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmfdotn{v}{4}
\end{fmfgraph}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

and you'll just have to compile twice (the second LaTeX run is needed only if the code for a Feynman diagram has changed or some new diagram has been added).

Comment: I did the first one after `mpost afilename` comment it gave `! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .1.` error for `\begin{fmfgraph}(40,25)`. for the second one I couldn't  install feynmp-auto.sty

Comment: @jackaraz Did you add the `\DeclareGraphicsRule` line?

Comment: it gave me very very small diagram

Comment: @jackaraz Yes, it's small, because that's what the code produces.

Comment: how can I install fynmp-auto.sty? tried [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/feynmp-auto) but couldn't do it.

Comment: @jackaraz What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: you mean texlive or texstudio?

Comment: @jackaraz TeXStudio is not a TeX distribution. If you have TeX Live 2013, you can install `feynmp-auto` with `tlmgr`, but this isn't possible if you have the Debian/Ubuntu TeX Live. So more information is needed.

Comment: using texlive 2013 and ubuntu 12.04 32bit. I did install full texlive package. shouldn't it include `feynmp-auto`?

Comment: @jackaraz As far as I know, Ubuntu 12.04 has TeX Live 2012; if you really have TeX Live 2013, do `apt-get install texlive-metapost`

Comment: It says that it already installed: `texlive-metapost is already the newest version. texlive-metapost set to manually installed.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14833/discussion-between-egreg-and-jackaraz).